# Legality of post-WWII expulsions in Australia

Tags: australia, immigration

After WWII, most Japanese people were mandatorily expelled from Australia unless they were born in Australia or had an Australian or British wife, according to [this site](http://lovedayproject.com/about/) (the same may have happened to Germans and Italians - I'm not sure). Was such a policy legal in that time, and if so, to what extent does the law differ in Australia today?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch did the policy only affect non-citizens?

Comment: By asking "...unless they were born in Australia or had an Australian or British wife," I assumed you were asking about non-citizens. If not, reedit the title.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch It would be reasonable to assume the government wouldn't deport citizens. Just like it would be reasonable to assume the government wouldn't lock up 98% of males of a certain ethnic background.

Comment: The US Government put ethnic Japanese, Italians and Germans who were citizens in internment camps during WWII. They were all but deported, since many lost their homes and businesses. One of those camps is right down the road from me, now a museum.